# What do I use in place of the removed onCreateView() method in android.support.v7.preference.Preference?

Tags: android, android-preferences

I recently decided to switch from

```
import android.preference.Preference;
```

to

```
import android.support.v7.preference.Preference;
```

and it seems that **onCreateView()** is no longer existing, is there something that replaces it? Originally I was overriding the method, but now I get an error instead because it doesn't exist anymore so it can't be overridden.

Comment: I also studied this a few days ago and found that It does not seem to be allowed to  customize the View of a Preference in the v7 package.If you find a way, please remind me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the `android.support.v7.preference.Preference` you need to use override the `onBindViewHolder`, check [this](https://www.hidroh.com/2015/11/30/building-custom-preferences-v7/)